# Docker CLI & containerd on Windows

Tags: docker, containerd

Is it possible to use docker.exe (CLI - client) and its daemon containerD instead of standard dockerd.exe (docker daemon)?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Does ContainerD works on your Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use containerd on windows. https://blog.devgenius.io/gentle-containerd-on-windows-guide-for-you-50d4a46daccf

For a CLI you could use NerdCTL and an alias so you can run commands like "docker run" etc.

https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl

Comment: Could not setup ContainerD on Windows :( I always get an error: `plugin type=\"nat\" name=\"nat\" failed (add): error creating endpoint hcnCreateEndpoint failed in Win32: IP address is either invalid or not part of any configured subnet(s). (0x803b001e) {\"Success\":false,\"Error\":\"IP address is either invalid or not part of any configured subnet(s). \",\"ErrorCode\":2151350302} ` when tryign to run sandbox pod. Any suggestions ?